# How to get the correct SiteContext for an Item when you only have the Item

Tags: best-practices, multisite

You only have an instance of Item.

How do you get it's "official" site, assuming there are multiple Sites defined in configuration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably the most terse:

```cs
string itemPath = item.Paths.FullPath;    
SiteInfo site = SiteContextFactory.Sites
    .Where (s => s.RootPath !="" & itemPath.StartsWith(s.RootPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.RootPath.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`itemPath` is factored out of the LINQ for performance.

Comment: What happens if two site definitions point to the same section of the content tree?

Comment: Without knowing more, You will probably have issues with site resolution! Assuming this actually works, the logic will pick the first available site definition every time, as will Sitecore when doing site resolution. The order of definitions is important.

Comment: @DerekDysart Sitecore resolves sites from top to bottom as they appear in Sitecore.config. So the first match wins. Check the final order of your site definitions at this url https://{yoursite}/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Answer (score 15):

It's possible to determine the `Site` an item "belongs" to using the LinkManager. This is how Sitecore resolves links internally when `Rendering.SiteResolving = true` and expanding links or resolving the Preview Site when `Preview.ResolveSite = true`.

```cs
var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/my-item");
SiteInfo site = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ResolveTargetSite(item);
```

Possibly not the best use of the `LinkManager` and it feels a little dirty as a result, but this mean that you follow the same logic as Sitecore and should something change in the future then your own code will follow that same logic.

Comment: I like this approach and it's probably the most "correct".

Comment: The issue with this approach is that `LinkManager` is a wrapper for what may be a custom `LinkProvider`, so who knows what you're going to get. I think both solutions have merit.

Comment: Yes, it's a good point. Depends of course if the default `LinkProvider` has been inherited and then _this_ method also overridden. If you wanted to be doubly sure you were using the Sitecore provider a you could new up an instance of `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and call `ResolveTargetSite` on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware in which version this was introduced but at least in Sitecore 9.3 the other answers are outdated and should be replaced by utilizing the IItemSiteResolver interface which you can get through dependency injection.